# Visibility values defined in CSS not showing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code produces the result one would expect:

```
<script>
function Show_Visibility(){
    p = document.getElementById("i_button_2");
    alert(p.style.visibility);
}
</script>

<INPUT TYPE = "button"   id = "i_button_1"  value = "This is Button 1"   onclick="Show_Visibility()">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE = "button"   id = "i_button_2"  value = "This is Button 2">

<script>
p = document.getElementById("i_button_2");
p.style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

However if we define the visibility of button 2 as hidden in CSS, the button is indeed hidden when the page is loaded, but the Javascript alert message is blank.

```
#i_button_2{visibility: hidden;}

<script>
function Show_Visibility(){
    p = document.getElementById("i_button_2");
    alert(p.style.visibility);  
}
</script>

<INPUT TYPE = "button"   id = "i_button_1"  value = "This is Button 1"   onclick="Show_Visibility()">
<br>        
<INPUT TYPE = "button"   id = "i_button_2"  value = "This is Button 2">
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the styles applied via stylesheets:

```
alert(getComputedStyle(p).visibility);
```

From the MDN article:

> The object returned from getComputedStyle is read-only and can be used to inspect the element's style (including those set by a  element or an external stylesheet). The elt.style object should be used to set styles on a specific element.